# MVC5 application form results in multiple post requests on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

We have an MVC5/Razor application that last week suddenly started acting really weird. It's hosted on a Windows Server 2008 R2 (with IIS 7.5) and the problem started after installing Windows updates last week. Up until then the application was working just fine.

Problem is that when a user submits a simple form consisting of 10 text fields, 4 text areas and a drop-down list, the server doesn't respond properly resulting in an "Error_Connection_Reset" (in Chrome) / "Page Unavailable" (in IE11).

We use POST-Redirect-GET pattern with `RedirectToAction` in the receiving action in the controller which would normally result in a 302 response and redirect.

The form is rendered like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Controller"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="editor-fields">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Model)
    </div>

    <div class="clear-fix"></div>
    <div class="submit-area">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
}
```

The action has these attributes:

- `[HttpPost]`
- `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`
- `[AllowAnonymous]`
- `[ValidateInput(false)]`

We also use Google Analytics and jQuery, jQuery validate, unobtrusive ajax with Optimization (minification). Most JS scripts are included with `Scripts.Render`.

The application works fine when we access it from inside our own domain, but since all our users need access from outside, we need to fix this error. This could suggest a DNS issue but our IT support says DNS looks just fine and hasn't been changed recently.

Here's what we've done and found out so far:

- Log file in `inetpub\logs\LogFiles` shows **multiple (between 3 and 10) POST requests all with status code 302 but no following GET request**. And there really should be only one POST request and then a GET request!
- Log file in `%windir%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR` shows nothing interesting, just a bunch of `Timer_ConnectionIdle` "errors" whenever the web site reaches it's idle timeout value (which is the default 20 minutes).
- Inspected requests with Fiddler and dev tools in Chrome and IE11 and all shows the same request headers. With fiddler we get `[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes`. In Chrome Dev Tools it says `(failed)` in the Status column.
- Disabled caching and compression in IIS.
- Turned CustomErrors off in web.config file
- Added `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`in web.config
- Searched Google and SO for answers but so far to no avail
- Checked the recently installed updates from Windows Update regarding .NET 4.5.2 and related Knowledge Base articles but nothing that really seemed related to this problem was mentioned
- **Edit:** Also, we enabled Failed Request Tracing but we only get failed request logs for a missing favicon.ico in `inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles` folder

Funny thing is that if i put a check mark in "Disable cache" in Chrome Dev Tools, the application also works just fine. This could suggest that it's a caching issue which is also why we tried turning on Output Caching in the IIS.

Our next step would be to either fire up a new server (Windows 2012 and a more recent version of IIS) and install the application there *or* install WireShark on our current server to further investigate requests. But if anyone has experienced this behaviour and know a fix for it, we would rather just fix it for now. So, please, if anyone can help, please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem only seemed to occur to users outside our domain, we started thinking that this issue might be related to our firewall so we contacted our firewall provider and they confirmed that there was an issue with the latest version of the firewall software. As it happened, the firewall software was updated same day as Windows Updates were installed on our server which probably caused a bit of confusion. After reverting to the previous version of the firewall software, the issue has disappeared and everything is working as expected again. Phew!